# Sharepoint: View office documents directly (on the web)

Tags: sharepoint-2007, ms-office

I am looking for a way to allow users without the Office 20XX package to view documents in a Sharepoint 2007 document library. Ideally, it would allow them to open the documents directly from the document library, but if it's implemented through a web part where you select documents and such, that would be great as well.

It is not a necessity that people can edit the documents, they simply need to be able to view them. I am looking for something that opens both Word, Excel and PowerPoint files, but a solution that only covers one type still has interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2007, you can view Excel documents in Excel Services via Excel Web Access WebPart:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-excel-services-and-excel-web-access-HA010105476.aspx

For Word, you can use Word to HTMl Service:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/convert-a-word-document-to-a-web-page-HA010163780.aspx

Things are much more easier if you have SharePoint 2010.

Comment: From what I can tell, SP2010 has Office Web that allows direct view of documents in the browser. Does SP2007 not have anything similar? The conversion service only works for .docx-files, and a lot of my documents are .doc :(

Answer (score 0):

You could have a document converter, convert all your office documents to word format

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms518493%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Then use the word to web page document converter

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-server-help/configure-the-document-to-web-page-converters-HA010157537.aspx